# Is it posbbile to send email in Scratch Org?

Tags: apex, email-template, email-alert, send-email, send-an-email

today I tried to send email with scratch org in APEX but not success.
Although when create scratch I added these lines to file
project-scratch-def.json like below:

```
"emailAdministrationSettings": {
    "enableEnhancedEmailEnabled": true,
    "enableEmailToSalesforce": true
}
```

So is it possible to send email in scratch org? If it is possible, please let me know how to do/config to able to send email?

Answer (score 2):

The answers is yes, You can send emails from Sandboxes.
Maybe you can check if your org is sending emails and then try to get your APEX to run.

Assuming you create a fresh sandbox , you should be able to see on your accounts an activity board on the right side of the screen, you can select the "email" option and try to send an email to yourself.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you need to verify the email address of the scratch org user. This can be done by resetting the password for the scratch org default user